# My PC crashes without any message

Tags: cpu, power-supply

Is aerocool e80-500W compatible with Haswells?

Motherboard: asrock z87 extreme6

CPU: i7-4770

RAM is compatible with this MOBO.

I disabled C-states in UEFI howerver it crashes sometimes

CPU is not overheating

Comment: Not enough information to decide what may cause the crashing. Drivers is a big enough possibility for crashing OS. (Had Windows 7 OS fresh install, but as soon as we install GPU drivers, it crashed every 10-20 minutes non stop). Is this a fresh install? Have you checked Event Viewer to see if windows managed to record something there that may give some info about the crash?

Comment: no errors, win7 and debian jessie, maybe PSU is overheating or something?

Comment: Both Win7 and Debian are both crashing? So Driver is unlikely (not impossible). Max output is 500W but it is not necessarily what it can provide stable power out at that max output. PSU running out of power is not impossible. How many GPU and HDD attached? About PSU overheating, you will notice it as soon as PC crashed, feel around the PSU and see if it is overheating. CPU overheating is also possible, or RAM error (do memtest). So yeah lots of things to check.

Comment: no GPU, just IGP inside i7, memtest86+ 8 hours no error, cpu 8 hours prime95 no errors, it happens just randomly